# MySQL JOIN query not bring back correct information

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT login_id, staff, name, COUNT( company ) AS resp_1
FROM trespondents
JOIN tresults_new 
ON respondents.login_id = tresults_new.company
WHERE tresults_new.sdate =  'NOV2014'
AND company =  'hh77yt6'
GROUP BY name
```

Within the table `tresults_new` there is data for two dates:

```
MAY2014
NOV2014
```

The part of the query I am having a problem with is `COUNT( company ) AS resp_1` - in the above query it brings back **158**.  This is in fact the total for **both** MAY2014 and NOV2014.

As you can see from the above query I am **trying to bring back the total for just NOV2014**, hence:

```
WHERE tresults_new.sdate =  'NOV2014'
```

Where am I going wrong with the above query, can anyone spot where I have gone wrong?  Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

To show that the tresults_new only has the above two dates, have run the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM tresults_new GROUP BY sdate
```

Output of this is (edited to remove identifiable information):

```
result_id   timestamp           sdate   
4293        2014-06-16 14:26:24 MAY2014 
1           2014-11-24 11:26:20 NOV2014
```

Comment: Can you show the whole rows of your records?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `WHERE` with `AND`?

Comment: @Jens - thanks for reply - what do you need to see?  I have just updated the above, if that helps.

Comment: @Homer_J I need to see the records where name = `MAY2014` and `NOV2014` with all other attributes.

Comment: @Charvee - it will indeed be one company, that is correct.

Comment: Are all tables prefixed with the letter `t`? How odd.

Comment: @Strawberry - really?

Comment: Can you just add count(Distinct company)?

Comment: Your original query is not bringing back data from `tresults_new.sdate =  'MAY2014'`.  Either that is not the query you are running or you have some other problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - yup, clearly that's the case but I cannot work out why :(

Comment: @Homer_J . . . Neither can we, because we really don't know what is in your data.  Perhaps you can get a smaller example and put it up on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff appreciate that - will have a go at getting it on there.  Too much data to strip out etc. but will try, cheers.

Comment: @Homer_J Yes. Unless otherwise informed, I think it's safe to assume that any object encountered in an RDBMS is a table. Also, what if you had a table like `roll`, `ramp`, or even `able`? That said, I think there is merit in prefixing *views* with `v_`, but each to his own.

Comment: It's nto something simple like you need to have all the select columns in your group by that are not aggregated is it? `GROUP BY login_id, staff, name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT login_id, staff, name, COUNT( company ) AS resp_1
FROM trespondents
JOIN (select * from tresults_new  where sdate= 'NOV2014' and company =  'hh77yt6') aa
ON respondents.login_id = aa.company
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 'MySQL returned an empty result set'.

Comment: Now brings back 158 again.